# Error al crear un procedimiento con condicional

Tags: oracle, plsql

Estoy intentando crear un procedimiento en Oracle SQL Developer(11C) al que se le pasan 3 parametros de esta forma:

```
Execute CAMBIAR_PRECIO_PRODUCTOS('AR12',25,TRUE)
```

Y el procedimiento seria el siguiente:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CAMBIAR_PRECIO_PRODUCTOS(
    CA IN VARCHAR, VAR_PRECIO IN NUMBER, IVA IN BOOLEAN
) IS 
DECLARE 
    VERDADERO BOOLEAN :=TRUE; 
    FALSO BOOLEAN :=FALSE; 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE PRODUCTOS 
    SET PRECIO= VAR_PRECIO 
    WHERE CÓDIGOARTÍCULO=CA 
        AND 
            IF IVA VERDADERO TRUE THEN PRODUCTOS.PRECIO= VAR_PRECIO*1.21 
            ELSE  PRODUCTOS.PRECIO= VAR_PRECIO 
    END IF; 
END;
```

Pero a la hora de ejecutar el código, me tira el siguiente error:

```
Error(1,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete    exists prior external language The symbol "begin" was substituted for "DECLARE" to continue. 
    Error(6,5): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one of the following:     ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>    continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev    sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval    date <a string literal with character set specification>    <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe    <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>    <an alternativel
```

Parece que es un error de sintaxis, pero el código lo he puesto mirando la documentación oficial y no veo donde esta el fallo

Answer (score 0):

Como te cito abajo desde la página de Oracle, no es posible pasar como parametro un boolean en un procedimiento, asi que tienes que cambiar la manera de entrar un valor binario al procedimiento, ya sea con un `CHAR` o un `NUMBER`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CAMBIAR_PRECIO_PRODUCTOS(CA IN VARCHAR, VAR_PRECIO IN NUMBER, IVA IN CHAR) AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE PRODUCTOS 
  SET PRECIO = 
    CASE 
     WHEN IVA = 'S' THEN VAR_PRECIO*1.21
     ELSE VAR_PRECIO
    END
  WHERE CÓDIGOARTÍCULO = CA
END;
```

> Due to a restriction in the OCI layer, the JDBC drivers do not support the passing of Boolean parameters to PL/SQL stored procedures.

Comment: Esque me equivoque al escribir el código y en vez de un 0 es un TRUE(lo he editado). Sirve para que si le pasas por parametro TRUE te aplique el IVA al precio del producto, y sino no te lo aplique. Tu has aplicado un CASE, pero... no se podría hacer con un IF?

Comment: Por otro lado, PRODUCTOS.PRECIO= PRODUCTOS.PRECIO  seria realmente  PRODUCTOS.PRECIO=VAR_PRECIO

Comment: Entonces si el parametro de entrada es true, te aplique IVA al precio que quieres hacer UPDATE y metes como parametro tambien no es asi?

Comment: Cómo podría hacerlo con un IF?

Comment: El funcionamiento es: Tu introduces el codigo del articulo que quieres modificar, introduces el precio nuevo y decides si quieres que se aplique el IVA poniendo TRUE o FALSE si no quieres que se aplique

Comment: He puesto tu código y me da error en la variable verdadero

Comment: Pruebalo ahora a ver si funciona.

Comment: Me aparecen estos errores: Error(2,10): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored Error(9,9): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended Error(9,12): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with    <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>    <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge

Comment: Prueba a poner WHERE CODIGOARTICULO = CA;
Puede que sea el ; faltante.

Comment: Ahora me aparecen 2 errores: Error(2,10): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored        Error(5,27): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "TRUE": invalid identifier

Comment: puede ser que sea por el numero, que en vez de ser 1,21 sea 1.21 o porque sea IVA is TRUE. Ahora mismo no caigo en que puede estar fallando ahi

Comment: El 1.21 ya lo cambie, pero sigue dando esos errores, el IS en el TRUE me da otro error distinto: Error(5,28): PL/SQL: ORA-00908: missing NULL keyword

Comment: vale, pues la palabra IS va siempre acompañada de NULL, vuelve a ponerlo como IVA=TRUE, y cambia el numero

Comment: No, si ya lo habia cambiado y me sigue tirando los dos errores: Error(2,10): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored Error(5,27): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "TRUE": invalid identifier

Comment: Pues viendo esto ahora no estoy del todo seguro que pueda operarse con boolean de esta manera, si cabe la posibilidad de que IVA en vez de declararlo como boolean lo hagas como un char que sea 'S' o 'N' o un number, que sea 0 o 1 arreglaría el problema simplemente cambiando a 'S' o a 1 en el CASE

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado, voy a escribir una respuesta

Comment: Ya lo tienes corregido.

Answer (score 0):

No se puede incluir una variable tipo boolean en la declaración de un procedimiento en Oracle, tan solo se puede pasar como parametro y la solución pasaría por convertir el parámetro boolean en otro tipo de datos, como por ejemplo un varchar o un tipo number de esta forma:

```
    <create or replace PROCEDURE CAMBIAR_PRECIO_PRODUCTOS(CA IN VARCHAR, VAR_PRECIO IN NUMBER, IVA IN BOOLEAN) AS    
  vIva VARCHAR(10):='FALSE';

BEGIN
  IF IVA = TRUE THEN
    vIva:='TRUE';
  ELSE
    vIva:='FALSE';
  END IF;

         UPDATE PRODUCTOS 
          SET PRECIO = 
              CASE 
               WHEN vIva = 'TRUE' THEN VAR_PRECIO*1.21
               ELSE VAR_PRECIO
              END
          WHERE CÓDIGOARTÍCULO = CA;
 END;
```

Otra solución sería pasar como parametro directamente otro tipo de datos, como un numero o un caracter, de esta forma:

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE CAMBIAR_PRECIO_PRODUCTOS2(CA IN VARCHAR, VAR_PRECIO IN NUMBER, IVA IN NUMBER) AS
  vIva VARCHAR(10):='FALSE';

BEGIN
  IF IVA = 1 THEN
    vIva:='TRUE';
  ELSE
    vIva:='FALSE';
  END IF;

         UPDATE PRODUCTOS 
          SET PRECIO = 
              CASE 
               WHEN vIva = 'TRUE' THEN VAR_PRECIO*1.21
               ELSE VAR_PRECIO
              END
          WHERE CÓDIGOARTÍCULO = CA;
 END;
```